# Normed space related question

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $p$ be in the range of $0<p<1$, and consider the space $ L_p[0,1]$ of all functions with 
$$ \|x\| = \left[\int_{i=0}^1 |x(t)^p| \, dt\right]^{1/p} <\infty$$

Comment: Show that it does not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: How can I show that here? Should I put $y$ as zero? Can you please explain a bit further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Idea:** show that it does not satisfy the triangle inequality by showing two functions $f,g \in L_p[0,1]$ such that $\lVert f+g\rVert_p > \lVert f\rVert_p+\lVert g\rVert_p$.

**For instance:**

Take $f$, $g$ defined by $f=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/2]}$ and $g=\mathbb{1}_{[1/2,1]}$.

**In more detail:**

$$
\lVert f+g\rVert_p = \left( \int_{0}^{1}{\vert f+g\rvert ^p} \right)^{1/p} =  \left( \int_{0}^{1}{1^p dx} \right)^{1/p} = 1
$$
but
$$
 \lVert f\rVert_p = \left( \int_{0}^{1}{\vert f\rvert^p}\right)^{1/p} =  \left( \int_{0}^{1/2}{1^pdx}\right)^{1/p} = \frac{1}{2^{1/p}}
$$
and
$$
 \lVert g\rVert_p =\left( \int_{0}^{1}{\vert g\rvert^p}\right)^{1/p} =  \left( \int_{1/2}^{1}{1^pdx}\right)^{1/p} = \frac{1}{2^{1/p}}.
$$
You can verify that
$$
1 > \frac{1}{2^{1/p}} + \frac{1}{2^{1/p}} = 2^{1-1/p}
$$
since $1^p = 1 > 2^{p-1} = (2^{1-1/p})^p$. (Since $p < 1$, we have $2^{p-1} = \frac{1}{2^{1-p}}$.)

Comment: Hello, Can you please explain why, $||f+g||_p =1$? I don't get that integral. Because, you assume f=1, and g =1. So, f+g =2. Please explain this a bit.

Comment: $f(x)$ is 1 if $x\in[0.1/2]$ and zero otherwise; $g(x)$ is 1 if $x\in[1/2,1]$ and zero otherwise. So overall, $(f+g)(x)$ is equal to 1 if $x\in [0,1/2)\cup(1/2,1]$, and $2$ is $x=2$. (That $2$ does not change anything since it's only on one point, but if it bothers you define $g=\mathbb{1}_{(1/2,1]}$ instead. Then $(f+g)(x) = 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ since either $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = 0$, or $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = 1$).